# Singly Linked List Implementation (With Nodes)

Tags: c++, linked-list

This code was recommended to me by my dear friend Jon after I wrote an implementation using arrays. With his help, I managed to create a Singly linked List similar to std::vector using Nodes.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    size_t _size;
public:

    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* next;
        T value;
        Node(T val) : value(val), next(NULL) {}
    };

    Node* head;

    LinkedList() : _size(0), head(NULL) {}

    ~LinkedList() {
        std::cout << "Linked List Deleted!" << std::endl;
    }

    void push(T val) {
        Node* node = new Node(val);
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        ++_size;
    }
    size_t size() {
        return _size;
    }
    bool empty() const {
        return head == NULL;
    }
    T pop() {
        Node* n = head;
        if (n == NULL) return NULL;
        head = n->next;
        _size--;
        return n->value;


    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> list;
    std::cout << "Empty: " << list.empty() << std::endl;
    list.push(5);
    list.push(6);
    list.push(7);
    list.push(8);
    list.push(9);
    list.push(10);
    std::cout << "Empty: " << list.empty() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Size: " << list.size() << std::endl;
    list.pop();

    std::cout << "Size: " << list.size() << std::endl;
    LinkedList<int>::Node* n = list.head;
    while (n != NULL) {
        std::cout << n->value << std::endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you compile with more warnings enabled.  That would alert you to these problems:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Weffc++       208038.cpp    -o 208038
208038.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class LinkedList<int>’:
208038.cpp:50:21:   required from here
208038.cpp:4:7: warning: ‘class LinkedList<int>’ has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
 class LinkedList
       ^~~~~~~~~~
208038.cpp:4:7: warning:   but does not override ‘LinkedList<int>(const LinkedList<int>&)’ [-Weffc++]
208038.cpp:4:7: warning:   or ‘operator=(const LinkedList<int>&)’ [-Weffc++]
208038.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T LinkedList<T>::pop() [with T = int]’:
208038.cpp:61:14:   required from here
208038.cpp:40:31: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
         if (n == NULL) return NULL;
                               ^~~~
208038.cpp: In instantiation of ‘LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T) [with T = int]’:
208038.cpp:27:22:   required from ‘void LinkedList<T>::push(T) [with T = int]’
208038.cpp:52:16:   required from here
208038.cpp:14:11: warning: ‘LinkedList<int>::Node::value’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
         T value;
           ^~~~~
208038.cpp:13:15: warning:   ‘LinkedList<int>::Node* LinkedList<int>::Node::next’ [-Wreorder]
         Node* next;
               ^~~~
208038.cpp:15:9: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
         Node(T val) : value(val), next(NULL) {}
         ^~~~
```

The lack of consideration of copy/move behaviour is particularly concerning, given that we have a pointer which we own.  The destructor is also faulty, failing to release the allocated resource:

```
valgrind -q --leak-check=full ./208038   
Empty: 1
Empty: 0
Size: 6
Size: 5
9
8
7
6
5
Linked List Deleted!
==18193== 96 (16 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==18193==    at 0x4835E2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18193==    by 0x1094BD: LinkedList<int>::push(int) (208038.cpp:27)
==18193==    by 0x109276: main (208038.cpp:57)
==18193==
```

Remember the guideline - whenever you write `new` or `new[]`, make sure you know where the corresponding `delete` or `delete[]` is!  (Don't forget that you need a `delete` in the `pop()` method, too).

There's no need for `Node` to be a class:

```
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node* next;
};
```

```
void push(T val) {
    head = new Node{std::move(val), head};
    ++_size;
}
```

I think it would be better if it didn't need to be public, either - there's nothing to stop broken code messing up the guts of the list.  We'd like a way to iterate through the values of the list without having to understand its innards, and without being able to accidentally change it (potentially breaking the `size` invariant).

Finally, `std::size_t` is written incorrectly throughout, and is missing its header (`<iostream>` is not one of the headers specified to define this type).

Answer (score 1):

### Fast review:

#### Be sure about what you post

Actually your code isn't a linked list, but a stack implemented in term of simply linked list, which the underlying data is publicly accessible. A linked list (even simply linked) have [a lot of things](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) that your implementation is lacking.

---

***Sidenote**: Please, you post a lot of code but before posting ask yourself if your code is really ready to be reviewed. "What's the purpose of my code?*
*How usable it is? Did it lack something or isn't fully implemented?"*
*Proposing codes to be reviewed isn't just throw as much code as possible in lesser time.*

---

#### Your code have a lot of [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project).

Even if the memory will be cleaned up [by the program termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677812/is-there-a-reason-to-call-delete-in-c-when-a-program-is-exiting-anyway), it's a good habit to `delete` resource that you allocated once you don't need it anymore. Because, yes, the OS *normally* will clean not released memory, but then, it don't call destructor.

[Consider using smart pointer](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/beginner-s-look-smart-pointers-modern-c) they are [better, safer, stronger](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/22/smart-developers-use-smart-pointers-smart-pointers-basics/) (© DP).

---

#### Misc

- Prefer the C++ `std::size_t` to the C `size_t` ([here's the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t))
- The member variable `value` have to be initialized after field `next`, because you declare it last. ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828037/whats-the-point-of-g-wreorder))
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` or `0`. To know why, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) (and follow inside's links)
- Don't be redundant in your conditions: As explained in the [Core Guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#es87-dont-add-redundant--or--to-conditions), comparing a pointer to nullptr in a condition, not only is useless, but it's also much more verbose.
- Returning `NULL` in case of empty list when you call `pop` is a poor design and should be avoided. You have many better option here: returning a [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), using [exceptions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions) ans [many other ways](https://hackernoon.com/error-handling-in-c-or-why-you-should-use-eithers-in-favor-of-exceptions-and-error-codes-f0640912eb45).
- Be consistent: at one place, you use **pre**-crementation, at other you use **post**-decrementation. There's a [huge list of SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20pre-increment%20post-increment) talking about post that.
- Take care that [memory allocation can fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833143/how-to-check-memory-allocation-failures-with-new-operator).