# Singly linked list class

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I have created this program about using a singly linked list class that implements several functions: `Add`, `Display` and `Sort`.

Could you suggest me how to make my code better and which functions to include in the future?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// ----------------------------------------------------
class Node {
private:
    int value;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(int v) { value = v; next = NULL; }
    void Add(int v);
    void Print();
    void SortValues();
    void SortNodes();
};
// ----------------------------------------------------
void Node::Add(int v)
{
    Node *newItem = new Node(v);
    Node *temp = this;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newItem;
}
void Node::Print()
{
    Node *temp = this;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << "  " << temp << " : " << temp->value << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void Node::SortValues()
{ 
    Node *swapCandidate = next;
    Node *current;
    Node *min;
    //    L* temp;
    // Look at every value
    while (swapCandidate != NULL)
    {
        current = swapCandidate;
        min = swapCandidate;
        // ------------------------------
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (current->value < min->value)
            {
                min = current;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
            if(min != swapCandidate)
            {
                int tempV = min->value;
                min->value = swapCandidate->value;
                swapCandidate->value = tempV;
            }
         // ------------------------------
         swapCandidate = swapCandidate->next;
         }
     }
     // ----------------------------------------------------
void main()
{
// Sort - moving values
Node *myList = new Node(0);
myList->Add(15);
myList->Add(3);
myList->Add(20);
myList->Add(1);
myList->Print();
myList->SortValues();
cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    myList->Print();
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Don't use `using namespace std;`

[It's bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/5416291) that can cause a lot of problems that are easy to avoid, most people are used to the prefix, and three letters aren't that hard to type.

---

### Don't use `system("pause")`

It's not portable and [there are better ways to hold the console open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908512/c-hold-the-console-window-open).

---

### Prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`

`NULL` is a macro that will be silently converted to 0 whenever possible. `nullptr` is a language extension and will only work contextually with pointers.

---

### Use proper encapsulation

A linked list should be a class that acts as a container of Nodes. Your `Node` class should not know how to sort all `Node`s. This is the job of the container. Furthermore `Node`s are an implementation detail that should not be exposed to the user.

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    // user functions should go here
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int value;
        Node* next{ nullptr };
    }
}
```

A few things to note.

- I put the `public` section first. This way anyone reading the code
  will know what functions and variables are available to them.
- I used `struct` for the `Node` since it represents plain data. It is
  also easier to use because `struct` is default `public` so the
  `LinkedList` will be able to access it easily (But since it is
  properly encapsulated inside the container nothing else can.)
- I initialized new nodes to `nullptr`.

---

Printing and Sorting aren't typically done as member functions. They should be standalone functions that accept a container, or a range of a container to perform their tasks.

---

### Use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) whenever possible

[You shouldn't be manually allocating memory.](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-raii) Especially since you aren't freeing it. Every instance of `new` should come with an instance of `delete` but you [shouldn't be using them](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete) at all.

---

### Prefer `'\n'` to `std::endl`

`std::endl` does more than just move to the next line. [It is generally preferred not to use it casually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

---

Keep working on it. Try to implement the container with some of the member functions found at [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Browse [The Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) from time to time. And bring us more code to review.

Answer (score 3):

#### Care about [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project) and memory allocation

Even if the memory will be cleaned up [by the program termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677812/is-there-a-reason-to-call-delete-in-c-when-a-program-is-exiting-anyway), it's a good habit to `delete` resource that you allocated once you don't need it anymore. Because, yes, the OS *normally* will clean not released memory, but then, it don't call destructor.
Here, the good place to put deletion is the destructor of your class.

[Consider using smart pointer](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/beginner-s-look-smart-pointers-modern-c) they are [better, safer, stronger](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/22/smart-developers-use-smart-pointers-smart-pointers-basics/) (© DP). If you used smart pointers instead of raw pointer, your allocated resources would have been automatically released by the default constructed destructor.

Check [this reply from @TobySpeight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/208050/182616) for further information.

Finally, take care that [memory allocation can fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833143/how-to-check-memory-allocation-failures-with-new-operator).

---

#### Use `nullptr`

Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` or `0`. There's [a lot of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) (and follow inside's links)
Also, don't be redundant in your conditions: As explained in the [Core Guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#es87-dont-add-redundant--or--to-conditions), comparing a pointer to `nullptr` (or even worst, to `NULL` or `0`) in a condition, not only is useless, but it's also much more verbose.

---

#### Avoid `using namespace std;`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/5416291) that can cause a lot of problems that are easy to avoid, most people are used to the prefix, and three letters aren't that hard to type.

- Although it's "safe" to use it in some place (e.g. implementation files), as long as you aren't familiar with the features of c ++, [try to avoid it](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std).
- It led to a world of name collisions. (best case)
- It's source of silent errors and weird bugs. (worst case)
- If typing `std::` is so tedious for you, try to import only truncated namespaces. ( e.g. `using namespace std::string;`).
- If importing nested namespaces still too awful for you, try to do it [inside a restricted scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) (e.g. a functions) and not in global scope.

---

#### **Don't use `std::endl`**

Using `std::endl` send a `'\n'` and then flushes the output buffer. So `std::endl` is more expensive in performance. Instead, use `'\n'` and then, if you want to manually flush the stream, explicitly call [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

---

#### Constructors/destructor

- Prefer [member initialization list](https://arne-mertz.de/2015/08/new-c-features-default-initializers-for-member-variables/) for `value`.
- Prefer [in-class initialization] for `next`.
- Provide a constructor with only one parameter  and another with explicitly two parameters (without defaulted  `next`).
- Respect  [rules of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

---

#### Avoid `system (... )`

You should [avoid using `system('pause')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) and [all it family](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/).

- It's non-portable
- It's slow
- It's dangerous

---

#### Interface

- Don't put the `Print` method inside of the class. Instead split it into two function a `to_string` to transform your list to a string and a overload to `operator <<` to output the string representation of your list (via `to_string`).
- Where did you `Add` value? At the beginning or at the end? We know because we see the code, but user of your class don't. The interface is unclear, should be `push_front` or `push_back`
- Look at the C++ Standard implementation of singly linked list ([std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)) and doubly linked list ([std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)), and try to implement iterators related functions, useful for a lot of things.

---

#### Sorting

- Move sort method as free function
- Add an optional comparator parameter
- Rethink your sorting algorithm, it's not the optimal way. You can do it in less operations (think about "comparator" and iterator).
- Don't reinvent the wheel, use swap.

---

#### Misc

Also, don't use long commentary lines, it don't help improving readability

Comment: Most of this just duplicates the answer from 6 hours earlier.  Can you be clearer about what's new in your answer (or - preferably - just omit items already covered by other reviewers)?

Comment: @TobySpeight do you really think that my message brought no added value? *I started it early this morning from my phone, at work. So, I only seen the other response right before posting). IMHO, I go deeply on repeated subjects and I explain some  other things that he doesn't tackle.  If you think I'm wrong, feel free to delete my message or downvote it.

Comment: Not at all -  I just said it was hard to separate the added value from the rest.  It's inevitable that we sometimes write much the same thing as others when good reviews take an hour or two to write - I often find myself having to remove or re-write stuff just before (or just after) posting when I find others are making the same observations.

Comment: Yes, You're right. TBH, I threw some lines about encapsulation since his explanation was a way more complete. I tried removing other repeated things but can't without break added value or the general logic of the post. (E.g. the sorting part was introduced by previous subsections). And I confess that from my phone, it's more tricky than easy.